# R Markdown Tufte Template: Font Size of Table Content

Tags: r, r-markdown, tufte

I failed many times. I put `font-size:12px` in `th, td{}`, or `td{}`, or `table{}`.

Is it possible to change the font size of table content?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to an external stylesheet in the header:

```
---
title: "Table font size"
output:
  tufte::tufte_html:
    css: "table_style.css"
---
```

or inline CSS definitions per CSS-code chunk like:

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
 td{font-size: 12px;}
```
````

Comment: I tried the first approach before posting my question.  I failed.  

I tried inline CSS definition this time. I failed.